# Plotting shapes ontop of image with given co-ordinates - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shapes

I am building a web application that uses [skybiometry api](http://www.skybiometry.com). On their demo, they have a very nice user feedback after a face is recognized like the one below

[image]

I'm trying to implement a similar functionality. Was thinking of Jquery/javascript solution. Found a lead at http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/#demo-outline but not what exactly I want.

Given co-ordinates e.g from the api response

```
"center"=>{"x"=>62.4, "y"=>43.4},
"eye_left"=>{"x"=>74.4, "y"=>41.2, "confidence"=>53, "id"=>449},
"eye_right"=>{"x"=>61.6, "y"=>36.6, "confidence"=>54, "id"=>450},
"mouth_center"=>{"x"=>63.8, "y"=>52.0, "confidence"=>54, "id"=>615},
"nose"=>{"x"=>67.0, "y"=>47.2, "confidence"=>58, "id"=>403}
```

Is there a simple library I can use to plot this on a picture? Any leads or online tutorial I can reference will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use canvas element. Draw the image as background and whatever shapes you need on top. This case is simple so you shouldn't need a library to do that.

Answer (score 0):

i am sure you have an answer by now but if you check this out does the canvas piece just not the tool tip

https://github.com/Liuftvafas/FCClientJS

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, as they may become invalid if the link changes.